# Help me on proof of an equation.

Tags: polynomials

I wanna prove following equation
$ \sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{k=1,k\neq i}^n \prod_{j=1,j\neq k}^{n+1}(x_j - x_k) = -\prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^n (x_j - x_i) $

I have verified several numbers such as $n=2,3,4$, and try to prove it using mathematical induction, however I can't extend the 2 $\sum \sum$. Some guru told me to try resultant, but it seems to be sums of resultants, and can't be simply used.

Can anyone help me on this? thanks a lot.

Comment: $\prod_{j=1,j\neq k}^{n+1}(x_j - x_k)$ or $\prod_{j=1,j\neq k}^{n}(x_j - x_k)$?

Comment: $\sum_{j=1,j\neq k}^{n+1}$ is right, by verifying several numbers, this equation is correct. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{k=1,k\neq i}^n \prod_{j=1,j\neq k}^{n+1}(x_j - x_k) = -\prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^n (x_j - x_i)$

Denoting $A_i=\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^n (x_j - x_i)$ we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{k=1,k\neq i}^n (x_{n+1}-x_k)A_k = -\prod_{i=1}^n A_i$$

From here
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\prod_{k=1,k\neq i}^n (x_{n+1}-x_k)}{A_i} = -1$$

The last identity is just the  Lagrange interpolation polynomial (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Comment: @parfois; You are welcome!